# golang confluentinc kafka docker, can not connect in container

Tags: docker, go, apache-kafka, docker-compose

This is error message:

```
2024/03/07 08:10:42 started consuming from kafka
%3|1709799042.685|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:kafka:9092/bootstrap]: kafka:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#172.24.0.5:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
2024/03/07 08:10:42 error consuming from kafka kafka:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#172.24.0.5:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
2024/03/07 08:10:42 error consuming from kafka 1/1 brokers are down
%3|1709799043.684|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:kafka:9092/bootstrap]: kafka:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#172.24.0.5:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identi
cal error(s) suppressed)
2024/03/07 08:10:43 error consuming from kafka kafka:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#172.24.0.5:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
%3|1709799050.694|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: localhost:9092: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
2024/03/07 08:10:50 error consuming from kafka GroupCoordinator: localhost:9092: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1709799050.817|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: localhost:9092: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1
 identical error(s) suppressed)
2024/03/07 08:10:50 error consuming from kafka GroupCoordinator: localhost:9092: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) s
uppressed)
```

Important to notice that this is error from consumer
producer produces in the queue but it wont connect.

This is connection options consumer:

```
    c, err := kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092/bootstrap,kafka:9092,kafka",
        "group.id":          "myGroup",
        "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
    })
```

This is connection options producer:

```
    p, err := kafka.NewProducer(
        &kafka.ConfigMap{"bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092/bootstrap,kafka:9092,kafka"},
    )
```

docker-compose kafka:

```
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "22181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "9007:9000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: "kafka:29092"
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xms16M -Xmx48M -Xss180K -XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -noverify"
    depends_on:
      - "kafka"
```

Consumer:

```
  calculator:
    build:
      context: ./distance_calculator/
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: always

    depends_on:
      - receiver
```

Producer:

```
  receiver:
    build:
      context: ./data_receiver/
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

I've tried changing these bootstrap.service options a little bit but quite did not work.
Its important to notice that it was running when I ran without container

Really need help.